# Accessing element inside list initialization in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3 is it possible to access a list element inside this list initialization? I think, it's impossible, but I'm interested just in case it is.

For example, something like this:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3] + lst[0]
```

or

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, lst[0]]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `lst` is not yet defined when the right part is evaluated, so no

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Thank you for your answer! I'll take it on board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The entire right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated before it is assigned to the name on the left.  So you can't use `lst` on the right because `lst` doesn't exist until after the right-hand side has finished evaluating.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You satisfied my interest. Before that I hoped Python has some magic tricks for this case :-)

Answer (score 2):

You still don't have a name for the part of `lst` you want to access, so you cannot access it.

But defining a name is trivial:

```
left_lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst = left_lst + left_lst[2:3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've always done like so, but I thought that Python might have some magic tricks for this.